# LibGDX 3DSphere is changing shape while moving on the screen with mouse

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, game-development, perspectivecamera

I have created a sphere using Texture by calling createSphere() method on modelBuilder using libGDX. As it is 3D, I used Perspective Camera. I am trying to move the sphere on the screen with the mouse. Its working fine, but the sphere had been changing its shape while moving on the screen.

I tried by changing the position and lookAt of the Perspective Camera. Still, shape is changing. Can anyone suggest the solution.

Here is my part of the code:

```
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ball.png"));
    Material material = new 
    Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(texture));
    final long attributes = VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | 
    VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates;
    sphere = modelBuilder.createSphere(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 24, 24, material, attributes);
    sphereInstance = new ModelInstance(sphere);

    perCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 
    Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    perCamera.position.set(0f, 0f, 3f);
    perCamera.lookAt(0f,0f,0f);
    perCamera.near = 1f;
    perCamera.far = 300f;
    perCamera.update();
    [Here I have attached screenshot for the reference, in which the regular sphere changes its shape to ellipse as it is moving away from the camera.][1]
```